# full if then statement is not being read php

Tags: php, function, if-statement, post, boolean

I have a program that evaluates an if then statement and returns true or false

false = everything is good

true  = still need more info

so here is my code

```
function city_state_zip_requirement($parameters_ar){
    //clear requirements if all the address fields are filled and the first and last or company is filled
    if (!empty($parameters_ar['Address']) && !empty($parameters_ar['City']) && !empty($parameters_ar['State']) && !empty($parameters_ar['Zip']) && (!empty($paramenters_ar['First'] && !empty($paramenters_ar['Last'])) || !empty($paramenters_ar['Company']))){
    return false;
    // clear the requirement if the first and last name  or company fields are filled and there is no filled field in the address city state or zip column
    } elseif ((!empty($parameters_ar['First']) && !empty($parameters_ar['Last']) && empty($paramenters_ar['Address']) && empty($paramenters_ar['City']) && empty($paramenters_ar['State']) && empty($paramenters_ar['Zip'])) || (!empty($parameters_ar['Company']) && empty($paramenters_ar['Address']) && empty($paramenters_ar['City']) && empty($paramenters_ar['State']) && empty($paramenters_ar['Zip']))){
    return false;
    // clear the requirement if the email address field is filled and the adress fields are either all filled or all empty
    } elseif (!empty($parameters_ar['Email_Address']) && empty($parameters_ar['Address']) && empty($parameters_ar['City']) && empty($parameters_ar['State']) && empty($parameters_ar['Zip'])){
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }}
```

all the fields are pulled from a user form that sends data through $_POST

what I am trying to accomplish is if the user enters info into a first (first name) and last (last name) or company field the address fields must be either all filled or all empty (i.e. cannot have only state filled for example)

upon debugging the statement that is evaluating to be true (and therefore returning false) is the second from the top
the:

```
} elseif ((!empty($parameters_ar['First']) && !empty($parameters_ar['Last']) && empty($paramenters_ar['Address']) && empty($paramenters_ar['City']) && empty($paramenters_ar['State']) && empty($paramenters_ar['Zip'])) || (!empty($parameters_ar['Company']) && empty($paramenters_ar['Address']) && empty($paramenters_ar['City']) && empty($paramenters_ar['State']) && empty($paramenters_ar['Zip']))){
return false;
```

it doesnt seem to make sense that when a user inputs data into the form php is evaluating that the above statement is true (and therefore returning false) if only `parameter_ar['First']` and `$parameter_ar['Last']` or `$paramenter_ar['Company']` is filled while one of the address fields is filled

Comment: What do you think "`return`" does?

Comment: gives a boolean 1 or 0 in this case, yes?

Comment: It means you are never hitting your `else`  --  For debugging set your returns to `return 'inside if'` -- `return 'inside elseif'` etc etc etc  This will help you understand *which* return is happening .. And then it's up to you to figure out **why**

Comment: @Zak I am hitting my else statement except when entering data in the `first` and `last` field, upon debugging I found that the second from the top statement is the culprit `returning false` upon only entering a `first` and `last` and one of the `address` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code so that it only uses one return statement and make functions to validate your request param array based on the cases you want to evaluate. By breaking your code down into smaller pieces it will be more manageable. For example

```
function yourFunction($params) {
    $needMoreInfo = true;

    if (isValidCase1($params) || isValidCase2($params) ... ) {
        $needMoreInfo = false;
    }

    return $needMoreInfo;
}

// define your validation functions here
```

---

Edit

The condition you find strange is

```
(
      !empty($parameters_ar['First']) 
&& !empty($parameters_ar['Last']) 
&& empty($paramenters_ar['Address']) 
&& empty($paramenters_ar['City']) 
&& empty($paramenters_ar['State'])
&& empty($paramenters_ar['Zip'])
)
||
(
    !empty($parameters_ar['Company']) 
&& empty($paramenters_ar['Address']) 
&& empty($paramenters_ar['City']) 
&& empty($paramenters_ar['State'])
&& empty($paramenters_ar['Zip']))
)
```

Analysing the first part of the logical OR

Not empty: first name, last name
Empty: address, city, state, zip

This condition will evaluate to TRUE if first name and last name are the only fields filled out. Since a "return false" follows, in this case, FALSE is returned.

Read more about logical AND, OR, NOT if still unclear.

It could also be that there is an errore in the HTML form causing a submit different from what you expect bit this can't be determined with the code provided

Comment: I edited my question because I think I was being misunderstood as to what my question is asking, thank you for answering though

Comment: I will rewrite my code like yours, didnt think to do that and it is much easier to read. this has made me think my understanding of php is maybe wrong. I was essentially trying to do two if statements in one separated by the `||` if the left side was true then do some code if the right side is true then do some code, maybe that is just not possible in php either way it still doesnt make sense to me how it is ignoring the rest of the `&&` as it should match 6 conditions to be true but it is only taking the first two as one of the address fields are filled but still returning false

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt for the life of me figure out why PHP was ignoring the other `&&` in the statements after `$parameters_ar['First']` and `$parameters_ar['Last']`, as it turns out.

I was spelling `parameters_ar['Address']` (and the other fields) incorrectly, I was instead spelling it parame**n**ters_ar['Address'] once I fixed the spelling error the issues went away.

I am using Notepad++ and it seems I made the same mistake elsewhere in the file and so the autocomplete feature was bringing up what looked like what I was trying to type but was actually incorrect

This is why php was reading $parame**n**ters_ar['Address'] as empty, because there was no value assigned to them and therefore evaluating to true and therefore returning false.

Thank You

Comment: always develop with `error_reporting=E_ALL` in php.ini, then your error would have been obvious instantly, so fix your php.ini, it will save you a ton of time debugging.